# I am getting error “Encountered unhandled fault when running process” in process builder for roll-up summary workaround

Tags: flow, process-builder

I created a process builder and several flows to simulate roll-up summary fields on the Account from a custom object called Invoices; Invoice looks up to Account (not master-detail relationship). I am executing the process builder every time an invoice is created or edited. The flow variable that I am using in the Process Builder is the AccountId.

The invoice is updated via an integration every day at a certain time and at this time, i am getting the following error messages (about 2-5 emails per day). Is my only option to build a trigger, or is there a way to solve this issue?

I Created the following Flows (these flows are used by the process builder above to simulate roll-ups declaratively):
Roll Up 1-30
Roll Up 31-60
Roll Up 61-90
Roll Up 91-
Roll Up On Time

One example below:
[image]
[image]

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

Encountered unhandled fault when running process Roll_Up_Summaries/301700000000Dza exception by user/organization: 00570000001rdMq/00D70000000JHJq

**Error**

caused by element : FlowActionCall.myRule_1_A1
caused by: An error occurred when executing a flow interview.

An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1.
An error occurred when executing a flow interview. .

This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange

**Flow Details**

Flow Name: Roll_Up_Summaries
Type: Workflow
Version: 1
Status: ACTIVE

**Flow Details**

Start time(GMT): Wed Sep 16 18:01:32 GMT 2015
End time(GMT): Not Yet Finished
Duration: 10 seconds

**Decision: myDecision**

**Roll Up On Time: myRule_1_A1**

An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1.
An error occurred when executing a flow interview. .

This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange

**Flow Details**

Flow Name: Roll_Up_Summaries
Type: Workflow
Version: 1
Status: ACTIVE

**Flow Details**

Start time(GMT): Wed Sep 16 18:01:32 GMT 2015
End time(GMT): Not Yet Finished
Duration: 10 seconds

**Decision: myDecision**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the proper debugging process for flows ,but can you just add a step of invoking Apex(and here you can write the logic to update your Account records) from flows after you iterate over invoices.

something like this 
public class rollupSummary {

@InvocableMethod 
public static void updateAccount(List invoiceIds) {
  //get the account ids from invoice object
  //Query Account and update 
  // put debug logs to see the inputs 
}

i am sure there could be other solutions for it  :)